# Using fields from models in django-form-utils fieldsets

Tags: django, django-forms

Sorry if I have overlooked something in docs of django-forms-utils by Carl Meyer. We're using it for the getting fieldset in non-admin pages in django. Here is my code in forms.py:

```
class MentorApplicationForm(ApplicationForm):
        email = forms.EmailField(label='Email', error_messages={'email_exists': 'This email id has already been used. Please use a different email id to submit a new application. Or write to applications@mentortogether.org for clarifications.'},)
        dob = forms.DateField(label=u'Date of Birth',
                      help_text=u'Format dd/mm/yyyy',
                      required=True,
                      input_formats=("%d/%m/%Y",))
        class Meta:
           model = MentorApplication
           fieldsets = [('Personal Information', {'fields': ['email','dob'],})]
```

What I want is something like this:

```
class MentorApplicationForm(ApplicationForm):
        email = forms.EmailField(label='Email', error_messages={'email_exists': 'This email id has already been used. Please use a different email id to submit a new application. Or write to applications@mentortogether.org for clarifications.'},)
        dob = forms.DateField(label=u'Date of Birth',
                      help_text=u'Format dd/mm/yyyy',
                      required=True,
                      input_formats=("%d/%m/%Y",))
        class Meta:
           model = MentorApplication
           fieldsets = [('Personal Information', {'fields': ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email','dob',],})]
```

where I have defined 'first_name' and 'last_name' in the MentorApplication models and I don't want to redefine them in forms.py. Here is [the doc](https://bitbucket.org/carljm/django-form-utils/src) where it says that it extends from ModelForm and that's where I expected that it would take the fields from the MentorApplication model(mentioned in Meta). Can some one help me out finding the reason and also suggest me a workaround(I am quite resistant on redefining it in form, since I'll have to repeat myself). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was extending ApplicationForm (super of MentorApplicationForm) from the BetterForm. I should have instead extended it from the 'BetterModelForm'.